Why multiple background workers actions are not async?
I coded a simple application in C# WPF to perform actions on around twenty machines via the network.
I've created a Physical_Machine class, of which I'm placing twenty or so iterations in a collection for my WPF display. The class includes a non-static background worker, i.e. a backgroud worker per iteration that pings the machine. Here is the simplified code:
public class Physical_Machine : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    
    public Brush Color_Background
    {
        get { return color_Background; }
        set { color_Background = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private Brush color_Background;

    private readonly BackgroundWorker wkVerif = new BackgroundWorker();
    private string Name;
    private string IP;
    
    public Physical_Machine(string _name, string _ip)
    {         
        Name _name;
        IP=_ip;
        wkVerif.DoWork += Action_WkVerif;
        wkVerif.ProgressChanged += Progress_WkVerif;
        wkVerif.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        wkVerif.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        wkVerif.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void Action_WkVerif(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Ping pinger = new Ping())
                {
                    PingReply reply = pinger.Send(IP, 2000);
                    wkVerif.ReportProgress(0, reply);
                }
            }
            catch (PingException piex)
            {
                wkVerif.ReportProgress(0, piex);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Progress_WkVerif(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.UserState is PingReply lareply)
        {
            switch (lareply.Status)
            {
               
                case IPStatus.Success:
                    Color_Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 177, 254, 183));
                    break;
               
                case IPStatus.TimedOut:
                case IPStatus.DestinationHostUnreachable:
                    Color_Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 180, 180, 180));
                    break;
                
                default:
                    Color_Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 194, 130));
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (e.UserState is PingException lexception)
        {
            Color_Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 93, 81));
        }
    }
}

Here is the main window code:
 public ObservableCollection<Physical_Machine> Physical_Machines
 {
      get { return physical_machines; }
      set { physical_machines= value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
 }
 private ObservableCollection<Physical_Machine> physical_machines= new ObservableCollection<Physical_Machine>();

And here is how I iterate this:
        Physical_Machines.Add(new Physical_Machine("SRV01", "192.168.1.101"));
        Physical_Machines.Add(new Physical_Machine("SRV02", "192.168.1.102"));
        Physical_Machines.Add(new Physical_Machine("SRV03", "192.168.1.103"));
        ...            
        Physical_Machines.Add(new Physical_Machine("SRV21", "192.168.1.121"));

Everything is working properly.
However, the ping check is not done in parallel.
This is particularly noticeable if I run the program without powering on the machines. SRV01 remains “unknown” for two seconds and then changes to “unavailable” (or at least the corresponding color). Then two seconds later it's SRV02's turn, then 2 seconds later SRV03 and so on. For example, if I only have SRV21 online, when I start the program I'll have to wait 40s to get the information. This is because I have to wait for the timouts of the previous 20 machines.
Logically, since each Physical_Machine object has its own background worker, all pings should take place at the same time, but this is not the case. Why aren't the pings performed independently of each other?

Tbh, I am not sure whether to trust any of the two BackgroundWorker or Ping. The former probably would better be replaced with async Task and IProgress<T> and the latter ... hmmm ... not sure, maybe 3rd Party or homebrew, but that API looks antique and from what the docs say, it surely is.

@Fildor Is there an other way to do pings with a newer API?

I'd replace BackgroundWorker first and then test again. The problem with Ping - as far as I read in the Docs is that even the "SendAsync" method is just "pseudo" async. Meaning it utilizes a pool thread for blocking. Searching for nugets didn't really bring up a solution I would consider for production. On the other hand, ICMP may not be the most reliable tool if you don't have control over the network you are pinging.

I'm an amateur coder, I have no idea what kind of alternative I can use for presence tests apart from pings.
On the other hand, I think I can quite easily turn background workers into tasks. I'll just have to work out how to pass state change information from a task to the main window.

You basically do that via IProgress<T> / Progress<T>. That will also take care of the marshalling.

For Pings: If it's basically your LAN that you want to Monitor, Pings should be fine. At least you can make it work if it should not out of the box.

"Two seconds" allowed per Ping for a timeout? I used 250ms to get the job done; meaning, my scan runs on average 8 times faster. (But we're not in that much of a hurry that we need to do it in parallel; at startup). We also "remember" the last scan, so we can try those addresses first; based on the count.

There may be something else at play by the looks of it. In a console fiddle, the pings run in parallel - limited by the number of processors.

I have switch to Tasks and it's faster but still not perfectly. Maybe it's because the PC is old...

Writing code that infinitely loops with no way to exit is a bad idea. Your while (true) is potentially turning your computer into a room heater.

@Enigmativity How can I do a permanent status check without an infinite loop since there is no situation when the status is not checked?

@Ionnae - Use a timer. Infinite loops are bad.
